# db connection initiated multiple times by rails app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

`Connecting to database specified by database.yml` is called multiple times by my rails app, even when the MySQL RDS db instance is up and running. How do I debug this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Rails? Which version of the MySQL gem? (You can check the versions in Gemfile.lock, or with `bundle show`).

In database.yml, there's also a pool parameter which [specifies how many DB connections should be made](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html) (to accomodate multiple threads using the same database). By default, this is at 5.